# sending values from controller to views

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

How can I achieve this, I am sending data from view to controller then back to another form in view, then also I need to pick data on table in database and sending it to controller then to view,

Here is my controller:

```
 public function new_orders(){ 
   //data from views then to another form
   in views  $category_id=$this->uri->segment(3);
   $data['registration_number'] = $category_id;
   //data from model to view 
   $this->data["product_id"]=$this->select->get_product_id();
   $this->load->view("product_add", $data);
 }
```

My model:

```
function get_product_id(){
  $this->db->select_max('product_id');
  $this->db->from('products');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result_array();
}
```

I want a form in view to display registration_number at the same time product_id.

In view registration_number is displayed but not product_id, it seems to be undefined variable. Help me please to solve it

Comment: You are using two different variables, `$data` and `$this->data`

Comment: see my answer use $this->data instead of $data

Answer (score 0):

update your code with below, use $this->data instead of $data

```
$this->load->view("product_add", $this->data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make some changes in your *controller*

```
$this->data["product_id"]=$this->select->get_product_id();
```

as

```
$data["product_id"]=$this->select->get_product_id();
```

and in your *view* page you can take this value in an array as following

```
print_r($product_id);
```

I think this may be a hint for your issue.I you need more explanation please share your view page